# Javascript Advanced Array Manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given a truncated array of object

```
const catsData = [
    {
        emotionTags: ["moody"],
        isGif: false,
        image: "angry.jpeg",
        alt: "A cat looking moody",
    },
    {
        emotionTags: ["moody", "insomniac"],
        isGif: false,
        image: "angry2.jpeg",
        alt: "A cat looking moody",
    },
    {
        emotionTags: ["moody"],
        isGif: false,
        image: "angry3.jpeg",
        alt: "A cat looking moody",
    },
    {
        emotionTags: ["confused", "sad"],
        isGif: false,
        image: "confused.jpeg",
        alt: "A cat looking confused",
    }]
```

I would love to transform it into an array like below:

```
    {
        emotionTags: 'moody',
        isGif: false,
        image: ["angry.jpeg", 'angry2.jpeg','angry3.jpeg', 'sad1.jpeg'],
        alt: ['A cat looking moody', 'A cat looking sad']
    },
    {
        emotionTags: 'insomniac',
        isGif: false,
        image: ['angry2.jpeg', 'insomnia.jpeg', 'insomnia1.jpeg'],
        alt: ['A cat looking moody', 'A cat looking insomniac',]
    },
    {
        emotionTags: 'confused',
        isGif: false,
        image: ['confused.jpeg'],
        alt: ['A cat looking confused']
    }
]
```

Such that all images that corresponds to a particular mood are grouped in an array of images (same with their alt if possible). images that correspond to more than one mood can also be grouped in that particular's mood object too.

I tried doing the below:

```
 let emotions = ['moody','insomniac','confused','sad','dominant','hungry','relaxed','angry']

 let modCatData = catsData.reduce((allCat, cat,idx)=>{
  let imageArr = []
  if(cat['emotionTags'].includes (emotions[idx])){
    imageArr.push(cat.image)
    allCat.push({
      'image':imageArr
    })
  }
  else{
    allCat.push({
      'image':cat.image
    })
  }
  return allCat
  
},[])

console.log(modCatData)ere
```

I was hoping to be able to pick an emotion, test it against the object emotions, and grouped the images that correspond with it, but i have difficulty grouping the images so far.

would appreciate a solution or direction if possible.

Comment: What is imageArr? What is allCat? Why do you have an else inside the reduce?

Comment: Shouldnt each image array have the same number of elements as the alt array in the output? Otherwise how do you know which alt to associate with which image? Or, better wouldnt you be better to have an array of `{img,alt}` objects?

Comment: @Adam 'allCat' is the accumulator for the reduce(), 'imageArr' is the array I intend to collect the grouped images to

Comment: @jamiec, I thought about the problem with the alts, I could omit it if possible, the main concern is grouping needed images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the input you provided has no sentences like, "A cat looking insomniac" or "A cat looking sad" but your output includes those sentences. So, not sure what is your correct data.

Second, if I got your question correctly then you want to create an array of moods and group the `images` and `alts` of that particular mood in that single mood item. So you might try the following-

1. Run loop on mood array.
2. Filter which items are having the current mood.
3. Get the `images` and `alts` from the filtered items using the map function.
4. I used the Set operator to filter the unique images and alt in case of duplicity.

Here is the demo-

```js
const catsData = [{
    emotionTags: ["moody"],
    isGif: false,
    image: "angry.jpeg",
    alt: "A cat looking moody",
  },
  {
    emotionTags: ["moody", "insomniac"],
    isGif: false,
    image: "angry2.jpeg",
    alt: "A cat looking moody",
  },
  {
    emotionTags: ["moody"],
    isGif: false,
    image: "angry3.jpeg",
    alt: "A cat looking moody",
  },
  {
    emotionTags: ["confused", "sad"],
    isGif: false,
    image: "confused.jpeg",
    alt: "A cat looking confused",
  }
];

let emotions = ['moody', 'insomniac', 'confused', 'sad', 'dominant', 'hungry', 'relaxed', 'angry']

let final = [];

emotions.forEach(e => {
  let obj = {}
  let result = catsData.filter(cd => cd.emotionTags.includes(e))
  obj.emotionTags = e;
  obj.isGif = false;
  obj.image = [...new Set(result.map(item => item.image))]
  obj.alt = [...new Set(result.map(item => item.alt))]
  final.push(obj)
})

console.log(final)
```

Let me know if your data is something different, I will update the answer.

Comment: this exactly solves it and it's what I wanted to achieve. I really appreciate how simple, easy to understand and straight forward it is. thank you. It's a truncated array, so those 'alts' were cut out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the grouping using a .reduce() call on the source array.  Then you can just filter the result to a specific emotion you are looking for.

```js
const catsData = [
  {
    emotionTags: ['moody'],
    isGif: false,
    image: 'angry.jpeg',
    alt: 'A cat looking moody',
  },
  {
    emotionTags: ['moody', 'insomniac'],
    isGif: false,
    image: 'angry2.jpeg',
    alt: 'A cat looking moody',
  },
  {
    emotionTags: ['moody'],
    isGif: false,
    image: 'angry3.jpeg',
    alt: 'A cat looking moody',
  },
  {
    emotionTags: ['confused', 'sad'],
    isGif: false,
    image: 'confused.jpeg',
    alt: 'A cat looking confused',
  },
];

const modified = catsData.reduce((aggregate, item) => {
  for (var emotion of item.emotionTags) {
    let existing = aggregate.find((i) => i.emotionTags === emotion);
    if (!existing) {
      aggregate.push((existing = { emotionTags: emotion, isGif: item.isGif, image: [], alt: [] }));
    }
    existing.image = [...new Set([...existing.image, item.image])]; // Trim to distinct values
    existing.alt = [...new Set([...existing.alt, item.alt])]; // Trim to distinct values
  }
  return aggregate;
}, []);

console.log(modified);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object for grouping.

```js
const
    addIfNotExist = (array, value) => {
        if (!array.includes(value)) array.push(value);
    },
    data = [{ emotionTags: ["moody"], isGif: false, image: "angry.jpeg", alt: "A cat looking moody" }, { emotionTags: ["moody", "insomniac"], isGif: false, image: "angry2.jpeg", alt: "A cat looking moody" }, { emotionTags: ["moody"], isGif: false, image: "angry3.jpeg", alt: "A cat looking moody" }, { emotionTags: ["confused", "sad"], isGif: false, image: "confused.jpeg", alt: "A cat looking confused" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { emotionTags, isGif, ...o }) => {
        emotionTags.forEach(emotionTag => {
            r[emotionTag] ??= { emotionTag, isGif, image: [], alt: [] };
            ['image', 'alt'].forEach(k => addIfNotExist(r[emotionTag][k], o[k]));
        });        
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to hard code the emotions. You can use a simple `.reduce()`. Try this

```js
const catsData = [{emotionTags: ["moody"], isGif: false, image: "angry.jpeg", alt: "A cat looking moody", }, {emotionTags: ["moody", "insomniac"], isGif: false, image: "angry2.jpeg", alt: "A cat looking moody", }, {emotionTags: ["moody"], isGif: false, image: "angry3.jpeg", alt: "A cat looking moody", }, {emotionTags: ["confused", "sad"], isGif: false, image: "confused.jpeg", alt: "A cat looking confused", } ];

const result = catsData.reduce((acc, o) => {
    o.emotionTags.forEach(tag => {
        let item = acc.find(i => i.emotionTags === tag) ?? { emotionTags: tag, isGif: o.isGif, image: [], alt: [] };
        if (!item.image.length) acc.push(item);
        item.image.push(o.image);
        item.alt.push(o.alt);
    });

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i'm struggling to understand what is happening within the forEach(), specifically the find() and "??". How do i get clarity?

Comment: The `.forEach` is iterating over the `emotionTags` in each object and then adding each one to the `result` array. Eg. it will go over `["moody", "insomniac"]` and first add `moody` to the result array, then add `insomniac` @gudchyld

Comment: @gudchyld `find()` checks if an emotionTag exists in the result array. If the result (`item`) is undefined (which means the emotionTag doesn't exist) then a default object will be assigned to `item`. (`??` is basically for setting a default value if a value is `null` or `undefined`)

Comment: @gudchyld I'm finding it a bit difficult to properly explain it but you can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing